# How to implement a social media feed using MERNG?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, graphql

I've been working a project which is basically a social media website. What I've build till now is that the Users can create accounts, create posts, follow each other, edit their profiles.The followed users are stored in an array. Each post has a field of username, through which I can search for all the posts which are posted by that username.

What do I do to get the latest posts of the users in that array sorted?

Right now, I'm querying all the posts that are posted on the website using:

```
    async getPosts() {
      try {
        const posts = await Post.find().sort({ createdAt: -1 });
        return posts;
      } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
      }
    },
```

and the user schema and post schema both look something like this:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: ""
  }, 
  username: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  password: String,  
  email: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  picture: {
    type: String,
    default: ""
  },
  createdAt: String,
  bio: {
    type: String,
    default: ""
  },
  website: {
    type: String,
    default: ""
  },
  gender: {
    type: String,
    default: ""
  },
  phone: {
    type: String,
    default: ""
  },
  followers: [{ username: String, createdAt: String}],
  following: [{ username: String, createdAt: String}]
});
```

and

```
const postSchema = new Schema({
  body: String,
  title: String,
  username: String,
  createdAt: String,
  category: String,
  comments: [
    {
      body: String,
      username: String,
      createdAt: String
    }
  ],
  likes: [
    {
      username: String,
      createdAt: String
    }
  ],
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users'
  }
});
```

This is the link if someone wants to check the project's progress until now: http://dev.divuture.com

Answer (score 0):

To sort the data array by date :

example of data array:

```
let myPosts = [
  { ...
   createdAt: "2013/7/02"
   ...
   },
   { ...
     createdAt: "2013/01/01"
     ...
     },
     { ...
       createdAt: "2013/12/01"
       ...
       },
];
```

sort function

```
 function sortMe(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.createdAt).getTime() - new Date(b.createdAt).getTime();
  }
```

//sorting all the posts by date

```
  myPosts.sort(sortMe);
```

> to read more about sort function 
>   https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Comment: You didn't understand my question, my current function does the sorting. I need a function that loads an array of posts for only those users whose username is in the following array